# How is the graph of $y= | 3/4x +6 |$ related to the graph of $y = | x |$ ? Describe the order of the transformations too.

Tags: functions, absolute-value, transformation

The two possible answers I arrived at were depending on if you factor out the coefficient of 3/4 in front of the x.

If you do, the function becomes $y= | 3/4(x + 8) |$

- first transformation is a horizontal expansion by a factor of 4/3
- second transformation is a horizontal translation of 8 units left

If you leave function as is without factoring out the 3/4 coefficient in front of the x.
The function remains as given $y = |3/4x+6|$

The other possible answer without factoring out the 3/4 coefficient of x is:

- first transformation is a horizontal translation of 6 units left
- second transformation is a horizontal expansion by a factor of 4/3

Comment: factor it through so you get a horizontal stretch by factor of $\frac{3}{4}$ and move left $6$ units.

Comment: What is horizontal expansion?

Comment: it is another term for describing a stretch

Comment: I have heard about "horizontal jogging".

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

To see why the first is correct, consider the functions $f(x)=|x|,$ $g(x)=\frac34 x,$ and $h_1(x)=x+8,$ and show that $y=(f\circ g\circ h_1)(x).$

To see why the second is correct, consider the functions $f(x)=|x|,$ $g(x)=\frac34 x,$ and $h_2(x)=x+6,$ and show that $y=(f\circ h_2\circ g)(x).$

Comment: Wait the second possible answer that I posted:                      
first transformation is a horizontal translation of 6 units left
second transformation is a horizontal expansion by a factor of 4/3                                                           
                                                                                           
should actually be: 

first transformation is a horizontal translation of 8 units left
second transformation is a horizontal expansion by a factor of 4/3

Comment: That would *not* be correct. However, you *could* first do a horizontal translation of 8 units left, then a *vertical contraction* by a factor of $\frac34.$ To see why, consider $(h_1\circ f\circ g)(x).$

Comment: To see why your "correction" is not correct, observe that it would move the $x$-intercept to $x=-\frac{32}3,$ rather than to (the correct location at) $x=-8.$

Comment: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/waymakercollegealgebra/chapter/sequences-of-transformations/                                                                                                                            look towards the lower half of the page. under section titled: A GENERAL NOTE: COMBINING TRANSFORMATIONS

Comment: The source you cite is incorrect. It seems that they are wanting you to make a horizontal scaling about the vertical line corresponding to $x=0$ on the original graph--for example, in the case of $f(x)=(2x+4)^2,$ if you shift left by $2$ first, then to get the correct graph, you have to do a horizontal contraction about the line $x=-2.$ That's not how contractions/expansions work, though; they are always centered at either the $x$- or $y$-axis, depending on whether they are vertical or horizontal (respectively).

Comment: In your particular example, shifting by $8$ units left first would create a new graph with the point $(-8,0)$ on it. A horizontal expansion by a factor of $\frac43$ would then create a graph with the point $\left(\frac{32}{3},0\right)$ on it, but it is readily seen that this is not a point on the graph of $y=\left|\frac34 x+6\right|.$

Comment: The following statements would be correct: When combining horizontal transformations of the form $f(bx+h)$, you may first horizontally shift by $h,$ then horizontally stretch by $\frac1b.$ Alternatively, you may first horizontally stretch by $\frac1b,$ then horizontally shift by $\frac{h}{b}.$ When combining horizontal transformations of the form $f(b(x+k)),$ you may first horizontally stretch by $\frac1b,$ then horizontally shift by $k.$ Alternatively, you may first horizontally shift by $bk,$ then horizontally stretch by $\frac1b.$

Comment: Oops! Those formulas should say $f(bx-h)$ and $f(b(x-k))$ in order to make my statements correct. Apologies!

Comment: i was wondering about that. Thanks for the corrections and the prompt responses.